# How to create win/loss numpy array

Tags: python

I have a function that creates a random n by 2 array of integers such as:

`[6,6]`
`[6,5]`
`[3,4]`
`[2,3]`

What the function then does is use those arrays to calculate the sum of array elements (which my function does) and then use various conditions to determine if the sum equals a win, lose, or tie.

sum:

12 (lose) 
11 (lose)
7  (win) 
5  (tie)

Then what the function is suppose to do is update/create a numpy array based on (this is the part I am having issues with):

`win = 1, lose = -1, tie = 0`

which would create a numpy array like so:

`[-1,-2,-1,-1]`

If someone could help me that would be great!

```
def game_session(num_games=100):
    values = rand.randint(1,7, 2*num_games)
    rolls_array = values.reshape((num_games,2))
    for a in rolls_array:
        sum2 = a[0]+a[1]
        if sum2 == 2 or sum2 == 3 or sum2 == 12 :#lose

        elif sum2 == 7 or sum2 == 11: #win

        else: # tie/0 


    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function may seem pretty simple, but this is probably a fine time to refactor it a bit. I'd suggest making a function that takes a single pair of values and returns the score for it - this makes it easier to see exactly what's happening - and then calling that function for each row in your `rolls_array`. The `score` function might look something like this:

```py
LOSE = -1
TIE = 0
WIN = 1

def score(one, two):
    total = one + two
    if total in (2, 3, 12):
        return LOSE
    elif total in (7, 11):
        return WIN
    else:
        return TIE
```

You can then apply this to an array like so:

```py
>>> rolls = np.array([[1, 2], [5, 6]])
>>> result = np.array([score(*roll) for roll in rolls])
>>> print(result)
[-1 1]
```

To integrate this in your `game_session` function, then, you can remove the for loop and just change the return to

```py
    return np.array([score(*roll) for roll in rolls_array])
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! Unfortunately this is how the outline my professor gave me wants it. It is way beyond my currently programming capabilities.

Comment: I'm not sure what you need, then!